# How to print slip voucher by connecting android device to epson TM T-90 via USB

Tags: flutter, printing, flutter-plugin, epson

I have searched a lot, but does not find any source that use usb. They all use bluetooth or wifi to connect and print.

I know how to do it with network. I am looking if anyone know how to do when connected via usb.Because my epson can't connect to network.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.